# Detection of duplicate code

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, code-duplication

I am working on a project where i want to detect duplicate code.

Example:

```
function sumOfTwoNumbers(a, b){
        return a + b;
}

function AddTwoNumbers(a, b){
        var x = a;
        var y = b;
        return x + y;
}
```

These both function return sum of 2 numbers, as these both functions return same result, is there any way to detect that these functions are similar.

Can u please suggest what technology should i learn to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check how svn, github work. hope it will work

Comment: I didnt get, how does this relates to my problem?